# php myadmin - Adding a password for authentication

Tags: phpmyadmin

By default no password is required for accessing php myadmin, but I wanted to add a password for login.

After reading a few posts ,I made following changes to config.inc.php file :

1) Changed

```
   $cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'config';

  to  
   $cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'http';
```

2) Inserted a password in the line     $cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = '';

3)  $cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = true;

After making these changes, I get the login form, but when I login with username 'root' and the saved password , the login doesn't work.

Please suggest a solution.
Thanking you in anticipation.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to do it mannually. Just log in without password, go to users, choose root and change password there! UI way)

Comment: After going to user page,I tap on "Edit Previlege" on a root user.In this page there are two sections of "Change Password" and "Change Login Information/Copy User".I tried changing password through both ,but neither works. Any ideas.

Comment: Change Password section works fine for me) make sure that root has all the privileges and try once more

Comment: Then try this one: go to terminal (or cmd in windows) connect to mysql and type: SET PASSWORD FOR root@localhost = PASSWORD('yourpassword');

Answer (score 0):

After making these changes, I get the login form, but when I login with username 'root' and the saved password , the login doesn't work.

That's because it's asking for the root MySQL user's password, not the password you set in `$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = '';`.

phpMyAdmin doesn't have explicit permissions for itself; it simply passes along whatever username and password you provide to the MySQL server. See http://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/intro.html#a-word-about-users

When using auth_type config, the [username and password that are entered](http://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/config.html#cfg_Servers_password) in to your `config.inc.php` for `$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = '';` and `$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = '';` are used to log in to MySQL. With the other auth_types (cookie and http), those fields are completely ignored and whatever you enter in the login prompt when connecting to phpMyAdmin is passed directly to the MySQL server.

So you can remove the 'password' line, since it's not doing anything. What you probably intend to do is as Jahongir indicated and change your root user password. Note that you almost certainly have at least two root users and you probably should change the password for each of them. Which one you actually attempt to log in as depends on your connection type (tcp or sockets) and whether you're accessing from another machine on the network entirely. So it's easiest just to change them all and not worry about it.